# Qt GUI freezes while using waitForFinished.. Alternative?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

**What I need to do**
I am building a qt application that run a exe and pipe its output to other exe. (In my case `ffmpeg | x265`)
**What I did**

```
QProcess ffmpeg;
QProcess x265;
ffmpeg.setStandardOutputProcess(&x265);
x265.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
ffmpeg.start(ffmpegArgs);
x265.start(x265Args);
if(!ffmpeg.waitForStarted())
 return;
bool retval = false;
while ((retval = x265.waitForFinished(-1)))
{}
ffmpeg.close();
x265.close();
```

Every thing woks fine but the GUI freezes when the process is running.
**What I tried to solve the Issue**

```
void Basic::on_btnEncode_clicked()
{
    if(fileContainer -> getQueue() -> rowCount() == 0) {
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText("No Input to Convert");
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
        msg.exec();
    }
    QString file;
    int bitRate;
    QString preset;
    QString ffmpegArgs;
    QString x265Args;
    bitRate = ui->sldBitRate->value();
    preset = mapPreset(ui->sldPreset->value());
    for(int i = 0; i < fileContainer->getQueue()->rowCount(); ++i)
    {
        file = QString("\"") +  fileContainer->getQueue()->item(i, 0)->text() + QString("\"");
        ffmpegArgs = Addons::FFmpegExe() + " -i " + file + " -pix_fmt yuv420p -f yuv4mpegpipe -";
        x265Args =  Addons::x265Exe() + " --input - --y4m --preset " + preset + " --bitrate " + QString::number(bitRate) + " --output " + QString("\"") + ui->txtDest->text() + "/out.hevc\"";
        QProcess *ffmpeg = new QProcess(this);
        QProcess *x265 = new QProcess(this);
        ffmpeg->setStandardOutputProcess(x265);
        x265->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
        connect(x265, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(processStart()));
        connect(ffmpeg, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(x265, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(processFinish(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
        ffmpeg->start(ffmpegArgs);
        x265->start(x265Args);
        ffmpeg->close();
        x265->close();
    }
}


void Basic::processStart()
{
    qDebug() << "started";
}

void Basic::processFinish(int exitcode, QProcess::ExitStatus staus)
{
    qDebug() << "exitcode" << exitcode << "status" << staus;
}
```

but I always get the output as `exitcode 62097 status 1` and nothing happens.
What can I do to run the process so that GUI does not freeze. Please Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating the `QProcess`es on the stack. Meaning that when your function returns, the `ffmpeg` and `x265` objects are destroyed. This also kills those processes.

If you want your process to keep running after your function returns. They must be created on the heap using `new`:

```
QProcess * ffmpeg = new QProcess(this);
QProcess * x265 = new QProcess(this);
```

Now you also need to destruct the `ffmpeg` and `x265` objects yourself, otherwise you would be leaking memory. The following will wait until the processes are finished before their objects are cleaned up.

```
connect(ffmpeg, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), ffmpeg, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(x265, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), x265, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

Comment: ignore my previous comment. The process is started but it gives exit code as `62097`. this code means Qt killed the process. Any idea why??

Comment: Are you using `new`, as I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, I included my whole function in the question

Comment: That helps: `ffmpeg->close();` and `x265->close();` kill the process as well: see documentation of [QProcess::close](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#close).